# Legend each curve in a single figure from a matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

I want to plot four curves in a single figure from matlab, so I am using `hold on`. Furthermore, I want to create an legend to each curve, so I wrote the code:

```
clear all
x=linspace(0,10,100);
x2=linspace(-5,15,100);
x3=linspace(-10,20,100);
x4=linspace(35,40,100);

figure(1)

plot(x,x2)

legend('x2')
hold on 

plot(x,x3)

legend('x3')
hold on

plot(x,x4)

legend('x4')
hold on

plot(x,x)

legend('x')

hold off
```

But the result is that all my curves are in the same color, and just the last legend "`x`" has appeared in the figure (see it below).

[image]

How can I set one legend to each curve? All curves must have different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on your matlab version. In older versions (and in octave), plots added through the use of `hold on` get the same color. In R2015b (i don't know when this was introduced), the individual plots get different colors, but still only one legend is displayed.
[image: Plots using Matlab R2015b]

To get multiple colors and multiple legend entries, you can specify all data to be plotted in one call, the same for the legends:

```
plot(x, x, x, x2, x, x3, x, x4);
```

or

```
plot(x, [x', x2', x3', x4']);
```

For the legends, approach the same way:

```
legend('x', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build up a legend without knowing the number of entries before hand, you would want to search for "dynamic legends". See for example here:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/legend-semi-documented-feature